# How i post data on search-Bar website using python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, security, python-3.x, web

As all we know in web application we have get method and post data method.
Here my problem appear with post data.
For example i want to make my python code that access  for search bar of website by insert same values and submit (the website button), then check for the page.
How the code gonna be then if there any documentation about this python concepts!
I am totally confused
Note : i am just beginner in python.

Answer (score 2):

If the website relies on javascript, you're going to need to use something like [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) which will emulate a typical browser and allow you to insert information onto a page and execute javascript commands.

If, however, the search bar simply posts data to a URL. You can determine that URL and then use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) to post the data and retrieve the result.

```
resp = requests.post('http://website/search', data = {'term':'value'})
```

Comment: yes i forget to mentioned that the data that i'm gonna post will not passed to url.
the search is in background website like the authentication page action

Comment: @muhammadbouabid Then you will need to look into Selenium as I posted in the first part of my response